# How do I determine whether a given path string could represent a drive in the current environment?

Tags: c#, .net, path, mono

I am working with file and directory path strings in C# code that may be run on .NET or on Mono.

I would like to determine whether a given path string could be a drive (irrespective of whether there is an actual drive mapped to that path on the current system).

For example, consider the string `"m:"`. In some environments such as Windows, this denotes a drive, whereas in other environments, it might be a usual directory name.

Unless I want to hard-code a check for the operating system<sup>1</sup>, **how can I find out that (w.l.o.g.) `"m:"` denotes a drive in Windows (and preferrably even find out that this drive is actually called `"m"`)?**

<sup>1</sup>: Obviously, this kind of check is destined to fail.

Comment: [DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) might help.

Comment: @Filburt: This looks promising. I had not considered that class because in the docs it really does not become apparent that it can be used for non-existing drives. I will have to check what the method does concretely on a Linux system.

Comment: @Filburt: Unfortunately, it seems that [Mono's `DriveInfo` implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/DriveInfo.cs) will throw an `ArgumentException` if the drive does not exist. While this is in contrast to what .NET does, the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) are vague enough ("`driveName` does not refer to a valid drive", without any indication whether "valid" means "theoretically valid as an identifier" or "concretely present on the current system") to permit this interpretation.

Comment: I already suspected this could lead to exception-driven program flow which of course is not desirable.

Comment: @Filburt: It would be great if it allowed for an exception-driven program flow, but as I described, Mono's behaviour doesn't even allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about the [Directory.Exists(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2) in combination with the [Path.GetPathRoot Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getpathroot?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetPathRoot_System_String_)?

```
string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(FileLocation.Text);   // e.g. K:\

if (!Directory.Exists(drive))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Drive " + drive + " not found or inaccessible", 
                     "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
     return;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to check how `GetPathRoot` behaves when run on Linux. I'm not sure what the `Directory.Exists` call is supposed to achieve here, though, as it seems to do the opposite of what I was asking for ("irrespective of whether there is an actual drive mapped to that path on the current system").

Comment: @F-H On Linux you're going to have a hard time as a drive could be mounted at literally any path.

Comment: Not sure how that makes for a "hard time". The function that I imagine simply returns `true` for any string that would be a valid directory name on Linux, when it would return `true` only for strings like `m:` and `m` on Windows.